# golang byte and string Sometimes compatible and sometimes incompatible

Tags: arrays, string, go, byte

This is my golang code

```golang
package test

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestOne(t *testing.T) {

    bytes := make([]byte, 0)
    bytes = append(bytes, 1, 2, 3)            // pass
    bytes = append(bytes, []byte{1, 2, 3}...) // pass
    bytes = append(bytes, "hello"...)          // pass too, ok. reference: As a special case, it is legal to append a string to a byte slice

}

func TestTwo(t *testing.T) {

    printBytes([]byte{1, 2, 3}...) // pass
    printBytes("abcdefg"...)       // fail

}

func printBytes(b ...byte) {
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

These are some code in `strings.Builder`

```golang
func (b *Builder) WriteString(s string) (int, error) {
    b.copyCheck()
    b.buf = append(b.buf, s...)
    return len(s), nil
}
```

The param `s` can be regards as `slice` type when be used in function `append` .

But I defined a function `printBytes` like `append`,

when I invoke like this

```golang
printBytes("abcdefg"...)
```

The `"abcdefg"` seems like not be regards as a type `slice`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `append` [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append):

> As a special case, it is legal to append a string to a byte slice, like this:
>
> > `slice = append([]byte("hello "), "world"...)`

Other than this special case (and a [similar case](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) for `copy`), `string` is not treated like a slice type in Go.

"Built-in" functions like this are allowed to have special cases that don't strictly follow the general type rules in Go, because their behaviour is actually part of the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) itself. See [Appending to and copying slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices).